# remove activeOpacity from createMaterialTopTabNavigator tabs react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, touchableopacity

i want to make active opacity to zero when navigating from one to another screen in create Material Top Tab Navigator. i dont known how to achieve this. i used activeopacity={0} and also known we can disable opacity but from where ? thanks for helping

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import RecentNotifcation from '../Screens/RecentNotifcation';
import AllNotification from '../Screens/AllNotification';
import { COLORS } from '../Theme/theme';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function TopTab() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
    tabBarActiveTintColor:"white",
    tabBarLabelStyle: {
        textTransform: "capitalize",
    },
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#616161",
    tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
        height: null,
        top: '10%',
        bottom: '10%',
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.headerColor,
    },
    tabBarStyle: {
        alignSelf: "center",
        width: '100%',
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor:  COLORS.pageBg,
        elevation: 5, // shadow on Android
       
    },
}}
>
  <Tab.Screen name="All  Notification" component={AllNotification} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Recent Notifcation" component={RecentNotifcation} />
</Tab.Navigator>
 );}
```

this is my code

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand what you want. The prop `activeOpacity` is from the touchable components and a don't see any touchable in your code example.

Comment: exactly . that i am asking how can we remove opacicy from tab screen when onpresss to change screens.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the opacity feedback you can pass `tabBarPressOpacity: 1` on screen options. The code will be like this:

```js
// Rest of code above

export default function TopTab() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        // ...
        // Other screen options
        // ...
        tabBarPressOpacity: 1,
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="All Notification" component={AllNotification} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Recent Notifcation" component={RecentNotifcation} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

You can read more about [`Material Top Tabs Navigator` and all props in the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#tabbarpressopacity).